# keep-alive connection with Superagent

Tags: node.js, http, keep-alive, superagent

I'm running a node.js server A which uses superagent to issue HTTP requests to another server B.

I investigated the request on server B and saw the the header `connection` being `close` and the httpVersion being `1.1`:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('superagent');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('req.httpVersion seen on server:' + req.httpVersion);
  res.write('\nreq.headers.connection seen on server:' + req.headers.connection);
  res.end();
}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0');

request
  .get('localhost:1337/helloword')
  .end(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.text);
  });
```

This leads to:

```
req.httpVersion seen on server:1.1
req.headers.connection seen on server:close
```

However if I access the same server from a browser I get:

```
req.httpVersion seen on server:1.1
req.headers.connection seen on server:keep-alive
```

From  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-172 I learned that `keep-alive` is the default for HTTP 1.1 unless declared otherwise by using `Connection: close`.

So, my questions are:

- Why does Superagent / Node.js explicitly set the request to not use keep-alive / persistent connections?
- How can I force Superagent / Node.js to use keep-alive connections?
- How can I further influence the exact behaviour (how many connections to keep open, timeouts etc.)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be documented but you can pass an http agent to superagent with the function `agent`.
So you could create a keep-alive agent with this module: https://www.npmjs.org/package/agentkeepalive and pass it to superagent.

Something like this:

```js
util = require('util');
util.debuglog = require('debuglog');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('superagent');
var Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

var keepaliveAgent = new Agent({
  maxSockets: 100,
  maxFreeSockets: 10,
  timeout: 60000,
  keepAliveTimeout: 30000 // free socket keepalive for 30 seconds
});

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.write('req.httpVersion seen on server:' + req.httpVersion);
  res.write('\nreq.headers.connection seen on server:' + req.headers.connection);
  res.end();
}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0');

request
  .get('localhost:1337/helloword')
  .agent(keepaliveAgent)
  .end(function (err, res) {
    console.log(res.text);
  });
```

Comment: This does not work. It doesn't fail but superagent always creates its own agent. The param is only an options param

Answer (score 1):

Browers can reuse socket handle, so it send the header `Connection: keep-alive` to server.

If you want to keep alive connection you can send that header like this:

```
request
.get('localhost:1337/helloword')
.set('Connection', 'keep-alive')
.end(function (err, res) {
   console.log(res.text);
});
```

Comment: Hm, can this really be sufficient? The receiving side 'server B' can and will  handle it as a keep-alive connection. But I doubt that on the requesting side 'server A' this will be enough. In my opinion the 'server A' will still open a new connection on every request made. I'm not yet sure how to prove/verify this.

Comment: I don't know. But superagent is depends on `node.js http`, and `node.js http` support keep-alive for reusing sockets. http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener

Comment: @dknaus What happens when you try it like this? What's the result?

Answer (score 0):

**For superagent  .timeout(5000) is also available to use.**

```
                    await superagent.get(`${anyurl}`, { rejectUnauthorized: false })
                        .set({ "Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json", })
                        .auth(username, password, { "type": "auto" })
                        .timeout(1000)
```