# TCP session reuse in Superagent

Tags: tcp, keep-alive, superagent

I'm using `superagent` and while inspecting the network I noticed that superagent is creating a new TCP connection for each request. I'm using superagent for a sequence of requests which results in a large number of TCP connections (can reach several hundreds).

I tried to follow [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324362/1857251) and use `agentkeepalive` package however this approach has some downsides:

1. While superagent works out-of-the-box with http and https, `agentkeepalive` needs to be defined per protocol.
2. As a result of the previous section, in case I do an http request that redirects to https request I get an error of `Protocol "https:" not supported. Expected "http:"` since the protocol has changed.
3. As a result of section 2 the app crushes since with an `uncaughtException` (which happens only upon redirects and not when using the wrong protocol i.e. the http `agentkeepalive` for https request)

Needless to say that using `request.set('Connection', 'keep-alive');` didn't solve it.

So my question is: how can I reuse the TCP connection while using `superagent` without getting errors in redirects? Is there another solution to reuse the TCP connection in `superagent` beside the `agentkeepalive` package?

Answer (score 0):

Use this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/agentkeepalive
You can integrate it with superagent like this:

```
const request = require('superagent');
const Agent = require('agentkeepalive');

const keepaliveAgent = new Agent({
  maxFreeSockets: 50,
});

request.get('http//www.example.com/path')
       .agent(keepaliveAgent);
```

In this example, the max number of connections is infinity, but it keep, at max, 50 idle connections opened, with the default keep alive timeout set (30 secs)

Edit:

About the http and https protocol using agentkeepalive, what I did in my case was the following workaround:

```
this.agent = new (baseUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith('https:')
            ? Agent.HttpsAgent
            : Agent)(
            {
                maxFreeSockets: 50,
                timeout: 60000,
                freeSocketTimeout: 30000,
            },
        );
```

Assuming that baseUrl will always be used with this agent. While it may not be out of the box with the protocol, it is a very simple solution and I used it as a base class for all my REST clients

Comment: Hi, as noted in my question - I tried using `agentkeepalive` but it's not a good fit

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I just edited my answer with the workaround I used for the problem you pointed out